# Parameter selection for log distance path loss model

Tags: digital-communications, dsp-core, fading-channel

I am currently referring to the [following](http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~giri/pdfs/EE6002/book-cho.pdf) book *MIMO-OFDM Wireless Communications with Matlab* in which the log distance path loss model is given by the equation:

$P_{LD}(d)[dB] = PL_F(d_0) + 10nlog(d/d_0)$

where $d_0$ is a reference distance and $PL_F(d_0)$ is given by $20log(4\pi d_0/\lambda)$.

For a system operating at 2.4GHz carrier frequency, should I consider $\lambda$ as $3e8/2.4e9$? How should I decide upon the path loss exponent $n$ and what reference distance $d_0$ should I consider?

The environment I am trying to simulate is the cabin of an aircraft. So, I need to vary $d$ between $1m$ to $50m$ but I am unsure of $d_0$ and $n$.

Comment: Yes, $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the signal; typically you assume that it's narrowband enough that the path loss is constant over the bandwidth, so you just use a single value. In your case it would be the value you indicated. The path loss exponent that you use is a parameter of the path loss model that you're employing; [there are many of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_propagation_model) for different environments.

Comment: How about $d_0$ @JasonR?